# Error al agregar un boton en bot de telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

**Contexto:**
Practicando Python 3 decidí extender las funciones de un bot que estoy desarrollando y ahora le estoy agregando botones, ya he hecho bots básicos y no he tenido inconvenientes, pero actualmente no entiendo en que estoy fallando.

Desearía que por favor me ayuden, para seguir aprendiendo.

**Este es el codigo de ejemplo:**

```
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Message

buttons = [[
    InlineKeyboardButton("Ir al canal", url="https://t.me/sirdroppe")
]]

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats, func = lambda x: getattr(x, 'text')))
async def my_event_handler(m):
    if m.reply_markup:
        text = m.reply_markup.stringify()
    else:
        text = m.text
    logs = getlogs(text)
    if not logs:
        return
    aa,bb,cc,dd = logs
    if aa in ccs:
        return
    ccs.append(aa)
    full_info = f"1: {aa} 2: {bb} 3: {cc} 4: {dd}"
    DATA = f"""{full_info}"""

    with open('backup.txt', 'a') as w:
        w.write(full_info + '\n')
    
    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, DATA, parse_mode='html', link_preview=False, reply_markup=buttons)
```

he realizado muchos intentos, he leído por todos lados y no encuentro la solución.

**Lista de intentos y errores:**

intento 1:

```
    DATA = f"""{full_info}"""

    with open('backup.txt', 'a') as w:
        w.write(full_info + '\n')

    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, DATA, parse_mode='html', link_preview=False, reply_markup=buttons)
```

Error 1:

```
line 94, in my_event_handler
    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, text, parse_mode='html',link_preview=False, reply_markup=buttons)

TypeError: MessageMethods.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_markup'
```

intento 2:

```
    DATA = f"""{full_info}"""

    with open('backup.txt', 'a') as w:
        w.write(full_info + '\n')

    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, DATA, parse_mode='html', link_preview=False,
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))
```

Error 2:

```
line 94, in my_event_handler
    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, text, parse_mode='html',link_preview=False,

TypeError: MessageMethods.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_markup'
```

intento 3:

```
    DATA = f"""{full_info}""", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)

    with open('backup.txt', 'a') as w:
        w.write(full_info + '\n')

    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, DATA, parse_mode='html', link_preview=False)
```

Error 3:

```
Unhandled exception on my_event_handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\logs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 520, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProjet\bot_button\main.py", line 95, in my_event_handler
    await client.send_message(SEND_CHAT, text, parse_mode='html',link_preview=False)
  File "C:\logsPython\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 871, in send_message
    message, formatting_entities = await self._parse_message_text(message, parse_mode)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\logsPython\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messageparse.py", line 87, in _parse_message_text
    message, msg_entities = parse_mode.parse(message)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\logsPython\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\extensions\html.py", line 136, in parse
    parser.feed(_add_surrogate(html))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\logsPython\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\extensions\html.py", line 22, in _add_surrogate
    return ''.join(
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\logsPython\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\extensions\html.py", line 24, in <genexpr>
    if (0x10000 <= ord(x) <= 0x10FFFF) else x for x in text
                   ^^^^^^
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 911 found
```

y pues, estos son algunos errores después de varios intentos, he leido mucho antes de llegar aqui pero sin lograr solucionar este error.

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar más a fondo ya descubrí cuál es el problema:

Presuntamente, el usuario es in capaz de crear botones, es por eso que es necesario más allá del api_id y del api_hash se requiere el token de un bot que administres.

Hasta ahora sigo buscando la solución de crear botones
Agradecería sus siempre bien recibidas recomendaciones.